# How do I switch desktop enviroments with out logging out?

Tags: debian, linux-mint, gui, cinnamon, mate

I have recently had an issue with Cinnamon and am using Mate. What I want to know is, is there a way to switch back and forth between gui environments with out logging out?

This is a Linux mint Debian Edition machine.

Comment: So, a very long  time ago, there was a tool called `switchdesk` that could allow this. However, this was before the environments became very complex. Right now, you can try to kill one and start the other in the same command, so for example `killall -HUP cinnamon & mate` (not sure what the command for mate to start is). The issue here is that things will break and a mess will result. Short answer: no.

Comment: well that makes me a sad panda.

Comment: I've had stuff break after the switch even with reboots - had to purge packages to make sure everything was handed over correctly.